# Creating a function to sort table React, JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, sorting, jsx

Im trying to figure out a way to sort my rows array depending on the sortBy and order state. I currently have a handleSort function which is grabbing the column name and setting it to sortBy state and also toggling the order by either "asc" or "desc" but now I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate the rows depending on the sortBy and order state. I believe it's possible creating a long conditional rendering but wondering does anyone one have simpler way I might be missing. Your help is appreciated thank you.

```
state = {
columnHeaders: [
  "Meat",
  "Protein (g)",
  "Calories (cal)",
  "Carbohydrates (g)",
  "Fat (g)"
 ],
  rows: [
  ["chicken breast", "25", "200", "37", "8"],
  ["fried chicken", "45", "450", "21", "16"],
    ["baked fish", "15", "250", "30", "9"]
    ],
    sortedBy: "",
    order: "desc",
    query: "all",
    error: false
    };

  handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({ error: !this.state.error });
  };

  handleQuery = keyword => {
  this.setState({
  query: keyword
   });
   if (keyword === "chicken") {
   this.setState({
    rows: this.state.rows.filter(row => row[0].includes("chicken"))
   });
   } else if (keyword === "fish") {
    this.setState({
    rows: this.state.rows.filter(row => row[0].includes("fish"))
   });
   } else if (keyword === "beef") {
    this.setState({
    rows: this.state.rows.filter(row => row[0].includes("beef"))
    });
    } else {
    this.setState({
    error: true
     });
     }
     };

 handleSort = header => {
 this.setState(state => ({
  sortedBy: header,
  order: state.sortedBy === header ? invertDirection[state.order] : 
   "asc"
 }));
 };

  render() {
  const { columnHeaders, rows } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="App mt-3">
    <AlertDialogSlide
      open={this.state.error}
      handleClose={this.handleClose}
    />
    <Search handleQuery={this.handleQuery} />
    <Paper className="mt-3">
      <Header />
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {columnHeaders.map((header, i) => (
              <TableHeader
                header={header}
                key={`th-${i}`}
                handleSort={this.handleSort.bind(this, header)}
              />
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row, i) => (
            <TableRow key={`thc-${i}`}>
              <TableItem row={row} />
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  </div>
   );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should save the original data and the filtered data in different locations - e.g. the original data comes from the props and the filtered data is in the state. Because if you overwrite the data (like you do at the moment), you won't be able to e.g. search for "fish" after you've searched for "chicken", because the data was filtered to only include "chicken"-entries - all "fish" entries where removed and are not accessible anymore.

Second, if you want to set a new state depending on an old state, you should always provide a function instead of the state object to the `setState` function ([check out this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

Third, instead of using the if-else blocks in `handleQuery`, you can just use the `keyword` directly to filter.

And now to your question:
You can use the following code snippet to order and filter your rows:

```js
const { rows } = this.props; // assuming the original data comes from the props!
const { query, sortedBy, order } = this.state;

// filter the data (only if query is not "all"
const newRows = query === "all" ? rows : rows.filter(row => row[0].includes(query));

const sortedRows = sortedBy === "" ? newRows : newRows.sort((a, b) => {
  const valueA = a[sortedBy]; // get the row to sort by
  const valueB = b[sortedBy]; // get the row to sort by

  let sortedValue = 0;

  if (valueA < valueB) {
    sortedValue = -1;
  }
  else if (valueA > valueB) {
    sortedValue = 1;
  }

  if (order === "desc") {
    sortedValue *= -1; // if descending order, turn around the sort order
  }

  return sortedValue;
});

this.setState({rows: sortedRows});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback, ill defiantly make those changes for the given code snippet where do i place this? after the render ? I see theres a setstate there which I know I'm not allowed to use after the render ?

Comment: This code snippet should be called after changes to the query or to the order - so in `handleQuery` and `handleSort`

Comment: thank you, and from what I understand you recommend the row values a props instead of state? because currently its in a state

Comment: but then wouldn't this.setState({rows: sortedRows});  be invalid if i do that ?

Comment: I stored everything in context api and then seprated the state changes  and the table and got it to work properly i still need to figure out how to filter the columnHeaders depending on the state of "sortyBy" and "order" but I'm going to give it a few trys before I ask a new question but thanks for your help on getting me there closer i apperate it

Comment: Hey Lorenz Henk  if you get a chance I posted an updated one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016744/sorting-single-index-of-array-value-in-react-jsx

Comment: Hello @MateenKazia, I saw you already got an answer by someone else, is everything resolved now?

Comment: yes thank you very much for your help I had the answer the entire time I was just to tired to realize it once again thank for leading me there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035644/mapping-through-input-field-in-react-trying-to-store-the-values-in-state   I posted a new question if you're able to help thanks again man

Comment: The question was deleted. Just wanted to post my answer

Comment: Hello, sorry I had to delete that one because I already had the answer but I was to tired to realize it I probably shouldn't go full 12 hours end up getting way to burned out. anyways I appreciate  all your help  I have new question up if you're free https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134625/function-to-swap-values-in-nodejs-w-mongomongoose/55134758?noredirect=1#comment97010793_55134758