# Sorting single index of Array value in React & JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, sorting

I'm trying to sort rows of a table and change each column given the "sortBy" value in the state the state is dynamically changing but the function to sort isn't sorting the values properly .
The function is currently sorting but its sorting the entire array instead of the selected sortBy value  how do I fix this function so it sorts a single column rather then the entire array like its doing now

This is my state:

```
state = {
  columnHeaders: ["Meat", "Protein", "Calories", "Carbohydrates", "Fat"],
  rows: [
    ["chicken breast", "25", "200", "37", "8"],
    ["fried chicken", "45", "450", "21", "16"],
    ["baked fish", "15", "250", "30", "9"]
  ],
  sortedBy: "",
  order: "desc",
  query: "all"
};



const { columnHeaders, rows, query, sortedBy, order } = this.state;

const newRows = query === "all" 
  ? rows
  : rows.filter(row => row[0].includes(query));

const sortedRows = sortedBy === ""
  ? newRows
  : newRows.sort((a, b) => {
   const valueA = a[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)];
   const valueB = b[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)];
    let sortedValue = 0;
    if (valueA < valueB) {
      sortedValue = -1;
    } else if (valueA > valueB) {
      sortedValue = 1;
    }
    if (order === "desc") {
      // if descending order, turn around the sort order
      sortedValue *= -1;
    }
    return sortedValue;
  });
```

This is the map thats rendering the sortedRows variable

```
{
  sortedRows.map((row, i) => (
    <TableRow key={`thc-${i}`}>
      <TableItem row={row} />
    </TableRow>
  ));
}
```

Comment: `"16" > "8"` will be false, you need to convert into int by either parse or use `+`

Comment: parsing the sortedValue ?  or the const valueA & valueB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the column is a numerical column or a string column using [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). If the column is a number, then simply subtract them. Else use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to `sort` the rows.

Also, I have added `slice` to copy the array since `sort` mutates the original array

```js
const columnHeaders = ["Meat", "Protein", "Calories", "Carbohydrates", "Fat"];
const rows = [
    ["chicken breast", "25", "200", "37", "8"],
    ["fried chicken", "45", "450", "21", "16"],
    ["baked fish", "15", "250", "30", "9"]
  ];

const sortedBy = "Meat", order = "desc";

const newRows = rows.slice().sort((a, b) => {
  const valueA = a[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)];
  const valueB = b[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)];

  let sortedValue = 0;

  if (!isNaN(valueA) && !isNaN(valueB))
    sortedValue = valueA - valueB
  else
    sortedValue = valueA.localeCompare(valueB)

  if (order === "desc") {
    sortedValue *= -1;
  }
  return sortedValue;
})

console.log(newRows)
```

Comment: Implemented that but unfortunately its giving me the same result, its filter the entire row array instead of just one column

Comment: You want to sort only one column and keep the rest of columns in their previous position?

Comment: this is the link to the component: https://github.com/MateenCode/tablesort/blob/master/src/component/Tables.js, Yes just trying to sort one column based on the "sortBy" state which is dynamical changing with the onClick event

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, sorry. Won't that show wrong nutrients for different `meats`?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm bit tired so I'm not doing the best job of exampling. I want this function to sort a single column that clicked the name of the column is being stored in a state called "sortBy" the function is currently sorting the entire rows array but I would like it to sort by the index that associated with the sortBy value for example if the sortBy : "Protein" I would like just the Protein column to sort rather then the whole thing

Comment: So, if you sort on `Protein`, then you want to show chicken breast -> 45, fried chicken -> 25 and baked fish -> 15?

Comment: So if I sort I protein I would like 45-> 25 -> 15 but just the protein column to change nothing else all the other columns like, Meat, Calories ...etc to stay the same

Comment: Just to be clear: If sorted by descending `Protein`, you want this row -> `["chicken breast", "25", "200", "37", "8"]` which has all the details for `chicken breast`, to convert to `["chicken breast", "45", "200", "37", "8"],` which will show wrong protein value for `chicken breast`?

Comment: Im an idiot, the function works perfectly. I was just understanding it wrong, Thank you my friend.

Comment: hey man I just posted a question where I'm actually stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035644/mapping-through-input-field-in-react-trying-to-store-the-values-in-state