# Function to swap values in NodeJS w/ mongo+mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to create a route that takes in 2 dates and swap those dates with each other in the database.

the console is printing but the data in the db isn't changing

```
// @route   PATCH api/swap
// @desc    replace date
// @access  Public

router.put("/swap", (req, res) => {
  const firstDate = req.body.firstDate;
  const secondDate = req.body.secondDate;

  // console.log(firstDate, secondDate);

  // Card.updateOne({ date: firstDate }, { $set: { date: secondDate } });

  Card.find()
    .then(cards => {
      cards.forEach(card => {
        if (card.date === firstDate) {
          return card.updateOne(
            { date: firstDate },
            { $set: { date: secondDate } }
          );
        } else if (card.date === secondDate) {
          return card.updateOne(
            { date: secondDate },
            { $set: { date: firstDate } }
          );
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
    })
    .then(() => console.log("working"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Mongo UpdateOne Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne) UpdateOne takes 3 arguments **filter**,**update**,**callback**, so i believe u need to pass **_id** of the collection to change.

Update- find() returns a cursor and to use foreach convert it to an array using `find().toArray().then(..so on)`

```
// @route   PATCH api/swap
// @desc    replace date
// @access  Public

router.put("/swap", (req, res) => {
const firstDate = req.body.firstDate;
const secondDate = req.body.secondDate;

console.log(firstDate, secondDate);

Card.find().toArray().then(cards=>cards.forEach(card => {
    if (card.date === firstDate) {
      return card.updateOne( { date: firstDate } ,{ $set: { date: secondDate } });
    } else if (card.date === secondDate) {
      return card.updateOne( { date: secondDate },{ $set: { date: firstDate } });
    } else {
      return card;
    }
  });
}))
.then(() => console.log("working"));
 });
```

Comment: yes, I have that but it still wasn't working ill go ahead and update my current one to how i had it

Comment: I'm using date as my unique key it works outside of the foreach but not inside thats my problem

Comment: I just tried it unfortunately same result, if I place     Card.updateOne({ date: firstDate }, { $set: { date: secondDate } });  with and without the qoutes both work outside of the foreach function

Comment: So in the **if** block u are checking `card.id === firstDate` shouldn't u be checking `card.date === firstDate` because u are using date as ur filter mongo doesn't have **id** and **_id** returns objectID

Comment: whoops that actually just a typo thank you for that but even still isn't working updating right now

Comment: Why don't u use **foreach** provided by mongoDB like 
`cards=> card.find().forEach(card=>.. then so on)`

Comment: Hum, do you mind showing me? I never seen that before

Comment: I Updated my answer it should work but i didnt tested it so let me know if any error pops up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189923/discussion-between-shivam-sood-and-mateen-kazia).